# How to create csv file in powershell with dynamic name?

Tags: powershell, permissions, permission-denied, new-item

I am trying to write a PowerShell function that will basically create a file in the folder with a name that was passed to that function as `$fileName` argument.

Here is the function:

```
$mainFolder = "C:\testFolder\"
function checkIfExist($path, $fName) {
    if (!(Test-Path $path)) {
        $path = $mainFolder + "data"
        new-item -name $fName -type "file" -path $path -force   
    }
    else {}
}
```

The error:

```
New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\testFolder\data' is denied.
At C:\testFolder\test.ps1:9 char:3
+         New-Item -Name $fileName -Type "file" -Path $path -Force
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\testFolder\data:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

But for some reason if I switch:

```
New-Item -Name $fileName -Type "file" -Path $path -Force
```

to:

```
New-Item -Name "static name.csv" -Type "file" -Path $path -Force
```

it works perfectly fine.

I run that script as an administrator but still get the same results.

**Update:**

I run function by using this line:

```
checkIfExist($fullPath, $fileName)
```

Comment: How are you calling the function when it fails?

Comment: Start by getting rid of the parens. Also you should always edit your question to add details not use a comment.

Comment: Oh, and get rid of the comma too. Powershell functions are called thusly: `Do-Something Parameter OtherParameter`

Comment: If I get rid of the comma it gives me other error messages:
`Unexpected token '$fName' in expression or statement.`

Comment: That error does not match the code that you say you are executing.

Comment: It was bad on my part. I basically changed the call to `checkIfExist($fullPath $fileName)` which I know now is wrong and that's how I got the error. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function incorrectly, Powershell doesn't use the `function($param1, $param2)` format, instead it uses `function $param1 $param2` (using positional parameters) or `function -Param1 $param1 -Param2 $param2` (using named parameters).

You only seem to be testing for the folder path, rather than the file itself.

`Join-Path` can be used to create the full path to the file, which you then test for and only create the file if it doesn't exist.

If you want to add a `data` sub-folder, just pass it into the function with the param.

```
function checkIfExist($path, $fileName) {
    $fullpath = Join-Path $path $fileName
    if (!(Test-Path $fullpath)) {
        New-Item -Path $path -Name $fileName -ItemType File -Force
    }
}

#example 1
checkIfExist "C:\folder" "file.csv"

#example 2
checkIfExist "C:\folder\data" "anotherfile.csv"
```

Comment: My error was that I called the function in a wrong matter, thanks for pointing it out. I just picked Powershell yesterday and assumed that the methods are called in the same manner as in Java. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just for your edification ***methods*** are called like Java using dot notation and parens: $someObject.DoSomething($thing). ***Functions*** are not called that way.